# MSVC equivalent to GCC's -fno-finite-math-only?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ieee-754

On GCC, we enable `-ffast-math` to speed up floating point calculations. But as we rely on proper behavior of NaN and Inf floating point values, we also turn on `-fno-finite-math-only`, so that optimization which assume values aren't NaN/Inf

For MSVC, the "equivalent" to `-ffast-math` is apparently `/fp:fast`. However, like GCC's `-ffast-math`, it [also includes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/10/19/do-you-prefer-fast-or-precise/) the optimizations which assume that Nan/Inf aren't present. (Critically, is appears tests like std::isnan() aren't guaranteed to give "accurate" results.)

Is there an option for MSVC C++ compilation which allows you to take advantage of most of the `/fp:fast` optimizations, but still treats NaN and Inf values "properly"? (Or at the very least, guarantees that tests like std::isnan()/std::isinf() will detect NaN/Inf if they do happen to be generated.)

Comment: Most likely you won't find such a switch. As far as I know, each switch added to the compiler doubles testing efforts on Microsoft side. That's why they are quite reluctant to adding new switches now.

Answer (score 2):

```
guarantees that tests like std::isnan()/std::isinf()
```

Unlike GCC, MSVC (CL RC 19) doesn't actually optimize out `std::isnan` on the `/fp:fast` setting:

Another alternative that will never be optimized out is to call the C99 `isnan` or the MSVC intrinsic `_isnanf`. Or roll your own `nan` test against a known bit-mask, which can be generated with `std::numeric_limits::quiet_NaN`.

See:
https://godbolt.org/g/YdZJq5